# Syncing Outlook 2013 Calendar to Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, calendar, outlook

I've done much research on this and at this point, it doesn't seem possible, but I'm hoping someone more knowledgable than myself can help me with a solution. I have a client that needs to sync Outlook calendar with a Wordpress plugin. They need the WP Calendar to display on it's own page and also be on the sidebars, like many existing WP Calendar/Event plugins.

This is what I know:

1. You can connect a URL based shared calendar to Outlook, but it won't let you edit those calendars in Outlook.
2. You can publish an Outlook calendar to a WebDav service. But since all the WebDav calendar services I have found, you have to enter in a login/password to access your file. (I tested using Cloudsafe).
3. I have not found a Wordpress calendar plugin that can access WebDav files.
4. A possible work around is to sync the Outlook calendar to a Google calendar and then use a Wordpress plugin that will sync with Google calendars. BUT that would mean that each person in the company would have to install an run the Google sync service on their computers, which I'm not sure they are willing to do.

Any suggestions on a way to get this request working? Thanks!

Comment: Then why not use WebDAV? The credentials can be remember by Outlook or one could (ick) run authentication-less WebDAV. If that works, then it's just a matter of finding/writing an appropriate WP plugin or data proxy.

Comment: @user2864740 I'd love to use WebDav, but there doesn't seem to be any WP plugins that will allow a WebDav calendar.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to edit "shared" calendars in Outlook. This works for Outlook+SharePoint integration.

See [2.5.6 Synchronize a SharePoint List with Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd948481(v=office.12).aspx) which contains a very brief overview and links to the MS-STSSYN and MS-LISTSWS technical documentation. Like with the WebDAV approach, failing integrated security, the password must be supplied (unless running a truly insecure editable calendar). The Calendar is just a special kind of List.

Then it's just a matter of accessing said resource in WP as well. So much fun!

There might be a 3rd party library that already emulates a basic SP List WS; there is always SharePoint [any maybe even Office 365?]..

Comment: Thank you @user2864740 but currently they don't have Sharepoint setup and are not going to be using Sharepoint, so I need to think of another solution.